# Firefox extension popup: close the popup not the window

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I have create a chrome extension and now i wanna create an extension for firefox. I use most of the code in chrome extension.

But now i encountered a problem. In chrome, extension can have an icon on the toolbar and when clicked, there can be a popup page. But there is no popup in firefox. I use a [`panel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/panel) instead.

And the question is how can i close the panel? I have used `window.close()` in the panel for some event. But this will close the whole firefox window.

Comment: You question doesn't have any real info on what you are actually doing. What are you using to display your "popup", [widget](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.7/packages/addon-kit/widget.html) or [panel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/panel)?

Comment: _popup page_ in chrome is a page show up when you click the button. It is not a new window. It is not a `widget` in firefox. It should be a panel.

Comment: I know what a popup is in Chrome - but your question is about Firefox and there is no direct equivalent in Firefox. So far you completely failed to explain what your are doing **in Firefox**. Feel free to edit your post and add this information, I will revert my downvote then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `panel` is not a window - it is just a single tag in the XUL document (browser window's document in your case). You should use the API provided for this tag to manipulate it, in particular the [panel.hidePopup()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/panel#m-hidePopup) method:

```js
document.getElementById("my-panel").hidePopup();
```

Answer (score 4):

using

```js
window.close()
```

tested in FF 70/71

ref to https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/how-to-close-popup-browser-window/13977/4